# C#: Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_client", Description:"The OAuth client was not found.", Uri:""

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to integrate Google calendar in my web application. I have successfully integrate Google calendar and able to read events from my Visual Studio IIS Express server. But when I publish and upload my application on web server I have start receiving error

> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException: Error:"invalid_client", Description:"The OAuth client was not found.", Uri:""

**My Code**

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/key.p12"), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
          new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(/*My Service Account */)
          {
              Scopes = new string[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }
          }.FromCertificate(certificate));

        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Test",
        });

            EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
            request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
            request.ShowDeleted = false;
            request.SingleEvents = true;
            request.MaxResults = 10;
            request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

            // List events.
            Events events = request.Execute();
```

Comment: where are you hosting this?  azure?

Comment: this might help https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.cs

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem by using .JSON key instead of .P12 key.

I have download new .JSON key from google API console. and change little bit of code as bellow.

```
GoogleCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/key.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                     .CreateScoped(new string[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar });
            }

    // Create Google Calendar API service.
    var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Test",
    });

        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

        // List events.
        Events events = request.Execute();
```

For more detail please visit link from comment section. Thank you DaImTo.